# What is Pythonic way to share state inside one module?

Tags: python

I need to handle signals in my code and I am using global to share state between functions:

```
exit = False

def setup_handler():
  signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)

def handler(num, frame):
   global exit
   exit = True

def my_main():
   global exit
   while not exit:
      do_something()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   setup_handler()
   my_main()
```

Is there a way to avoid global variable in this case? What is the best way to share state in this case?

Comment: Do you really want to be doing `do_something` as fast as the processor will allow? If you have a specific time resolution in mind, you should call `my_main` from `handler` every `n` seconds.

Comment: @Asad it is simplified code for clarity. It doesn't do work  as fast as the processor allows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a class to encapsulate the module global, but whether it's worth doing depends on how much you really want to avoid the global.

```
class EventLoop(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.exit = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.exit:
            do_something()

    def handler(self):
        self.exit = True     

# It's up to you if you want an EventLoop instance
# as an argument, or just a reference to the instance's
# handler method.
def setup_handler(event_loop):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, event_loop.handler)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   loop = EventLoop()
   setup_handler(loop)
   loop.run()
```

Comment: A class is the way to go. If you have several such states, you can put the state in a "config class" and pass this config class to `__init__()` methods of several classes to allow them to share state in an obvious way.

Comment: This is necessary for multi-threaded applications where only particular threads should terminate-- otherwise everyone shuts down when they see the flag.

Comment: It's worth noting that using a class will create a (small) memory leak if the process keeps running after the signal is handled. The signal module will keep a reference to the `handler` method, which will keep a reference to its object. You may wish to make the handler to deregister itself with the signal module.

Comment: If the process keeps running, it's possible that it will receive the signal again.

Comment: @chepner Receiving the signal again won't do anything; the `handler` method is idempotent.

Comment: *This* handler is idempotent; signal handlers in general need not be.